# Works (publicly available) combining LUCAS with other European land data bases?

Tags: land-cover, land-classification, land-use

[EUROSTAT](http://epp.eurostat.ec.europa.eu/portal/page/portal/eurostat/home) provides the [LUCAS](http://epp.eurostat.ec.europa.eu/portal/page/portal/lucas/introduction) dataset, a multi-purpose survey on the state and the dynamics of changes in land use and cover in the European Union.

I wonder if there are any land classification projects (preferably public works), that make use of the LUCAS data base in combination with other (European-wide) geospatial data (remotely sensed or else) and/or land (cover and/or use) data bases.

In particular, I am interested in a nomenclature correspondence between LUCAS and other European schemes.

For examle, an attempt to assess CORINE's thematic accuracy using the LUCAS data set, is described in [Fine scale profile of CORINE Land Cover classes
with LUCAS data.](http://agrienv.jrc.ec.europa.eu/publications/pdfs/LUCAS_CORINE.pdf)

Answer (score 2):

**LUCAS**

This data is available in Vector and Raster Format here:

http://www.eea.europa.eu/themes/landuse/interactive/clc-download

This data was included in the Open Street Map Project:

http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/WikiProject_Corine_Land_Cover

more detail
http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Corine_Land_Cover

**RAMON** is another that is Combined Nomenclature, 2013 
http://ec.europa.eu/eurostat/ramon/index.cfm?TargetUrl=DSP_PUB_WELC

and expect your are familiar with **NUTS**
http://epp.eurostat.ec.europa.eu/portal/page/portal/nuts_nomenclature/introduction

Comment: This is the very first time I read such a statement (LUCAS = updated CORINE).  Any documents that support this statement?  For your information, the most up-to-date CORINE land data base is the one of 2006 (in fact, a product recently modified -- on 2012 -- available as a vector or raster data set) ([CORINE2006](http://www.eea.europa.eu/data-and-maps/data/corine-land-cover-2006-raster-2)).  The nomenclature is not quite the same (plese check [The LUCAS nomenclature](http://epp.eurostat.ec.europa.eu/portal/page/portal/lucas/documents/Nomenclature_LUCAS2009_C_3.pdf)). The term CORINE is absent.

Comment: not updated - but replacement/additional http://agrienv.jrc.ec.europa.eu/publications/pdfs/LUCAS_CORINE.pdf

Comment: Thank you for your time. I am aware of this document. And I forgot that it includes a table (which is of my very interest). Otherwise, LUCAS is based on field sampling, CORINE based on satellite imagery. They are different "things" and cannot replace each other. LUCAS might be useful to assess the thematic accuracy of CORINE maps, but that's all about it. And, as the paper clearly concludes, such a task is very difficult and probably will lead to non-reliable results. LUCAS uses 3m^2 sampling units, CORINE is set to 25Ha Min Mapping Unit. Anything I miss?

Comment: I will add the document you mentioned in my question.

Comment: LUCAS is *not* the new version of the CLC2000. LUCAS is a field-based land use survey. CLC2000/CLC2006 is a landcover map photo-interpreted from medium resolution (SPOT/IRS) satellite imagery. http://epp.eurostat.ec.europa.eu/statistics_explained/index.php/LUCAS_%E2%80%94_a_multi-purpose_land_use_survey

Comment: @Mapperz: I'd like to upvote your answer if it would be strait and clear answering the question. Due to the statement _LUCAS is the new version of the Corine Land Cover (CLC) [2000]_ I cannot do that. Would you like to edit your answer?

Answer (score 2):

The accuracy of the pan-European forest map 2000 was assesed using the LUCAS2001 dataset. More details [here](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0924271608001032)